# How to push objects that are inside array of objects into another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, append

I have a part of code that looks like this where I need to pick objects out of array of objects and push them into an array.

```
    var issues = await Issues.find({})
    console.log(issues)
    let issuesData = [];
    for (issue of issues) {
            console.log(issue)
            issuesData.push(issue['data'])
    }
```

The output of `issues` is

```
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("6346e32032eae0a8d1986bf0"),
    data: { no: 1, date: '31-10-2022', cover: 'path/to/cover/image' },
    articles: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    letters: [ [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("6346e37c32eae0a8d198a3bf"),
    data: { no: 2, date: '31-12-2022', cover: 'path/to/cover/image' },
    articles: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    letters: [ [Object], [Object] ]
  }
]
```

and in `issuesData` I want an array like

```
[ { no: 1, date: '31-10-2022', cover: 'path/to/cover/image' }, { no: 2, date: '31-12-2022', cover: 'path/to/cover/image' } ]
```

but I get an undefined when I push `issue['data']`

Comment: Do you see the `data` property when you do `console.log(issue)`?

Comment: What does `console.log(typeof issue)` show?

Comment: try `if (issue.hasOwnProperty('data')) { issuesData.push(issue['data']); }` in case some of your objects are missing the `data` property

Comment: `const issuesData = arrayOfObjects.map(obj => obj.data)`

Answer (score 0):

I tried and it seems working fine for me. However a better way is to remove the `for loop` and replace it with `let issuesData = issues.map(issue => issue.data)` to get the same expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply apply the map function which will take care of your problem.
Try this:

```js
const data = [
      {
        _id: "6346e32032eae0a8d1986bf0",
        data: { no: 1, date: '31-10-2022', cover: 'path/to/cover/image' },
        articles: [],
        letters: []
      },
      {
        _id: "6346e37c32eae0a8d198a3bf",
        data: { no: 2, date: '31-12-2022', cover: 'path/to/cover/image' },
        articles: [],
        letters: []
      }
    ];

const issuesData = data.map(item => item.data);
console.log(issuesData);
```

map() creates a new array from calling a function for every array element. map() calls a function once for each element in an array.